# Do ListAdapters need to be released, or is that handled automatically?

Tags: android, listadapter

When a user selects an item in a ListView, I display a new list based on their selection using a new ListAdapter in the same activity.  Do I need to release the previous ListAdapter, or will the ListView handle that automatically?

I'm allocating ListAdapters like this:

```
            ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, tempCursor,
                new String[] {"name"},
                new int[] {R.id.name});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What do you mean "release"? You don't "release" an adapter. If you're talking about a cursor, you have to manage that yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListView will take care of releasing the previous adapter automagically. You do not need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar situation in an Android activity where the activity loads a new ListAdapter based on selected checkboxes in the activity. I simply declare a new ListAdapter and set it to be the current one and it works, I do not need to "release" or do anything with the existing one.

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    populateCheckedMembers();
    adapter = new MemberAdapter(this, R.layout.members_row, checkedMembers);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```